# Does the 'SharePoint services' cert get auto installed with SharePoint installation?

Tags: iis, sharepoint

Does the below 3 SharePoint related certificates get automatically installed with SharePoint installation? I remember this was not installed manually.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5X0Bl.png)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are provisioned by SharePoint and get installed on the initial configuration of the farm.